# error building boost spirit code with in an old open sourced project

Tags: c++, boost

I am building an old version of voltDB on my liunx machine and I keep running into an issue with the boost spirit library. It may be possible that its a gcc version issue, any ideas welcome..

```
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:63:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid
[exec]      const int_parser   int64_p  = int_parser ();     
[exec]                                 ^ 
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:63:44: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
[exec]      const int_parser   int64_p  = int_parser ();
[exec]                                             ^     
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:63:68: error: emplate argument 1 is invalid
[exec]      const int_parser   int64_p  = int_parser ();
[exec]                                                                     ^
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:302:23: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
[exec]          void new_int( int64_t i )
[exec]                        ^

[exec] In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
[exec]                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdlib:72,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/boost/config/platform/linux.hpp:14,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/boost/config.hpp:53,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_value.h:17,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.h:13,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:6:

[exec] /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:197:1: note: candidates are: typedef long int int64_t
[exec]  __intN_t (64, __DI__);
[exec]  ^

[exec] In file included from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_value.h:18:0,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.h:13,
[exec]                  from ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:6:
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/boost/cstdint.hpp:301:50: note:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::int64_t
[exec]       typedef  ::boost::long_long_type            int64_t;
[exec]                                                   ^

[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:302:23: error: 'int64_t' has not been declared
[exec]          void new_int( int64_t i )
[exec]                        ^

[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp: In constructor '{anonymous}::Json_grammer::definition::definition(const {anonymous}::Json_grammer&)':
[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:455:49: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
[exec]                  typedef function Int_action;
[exec]                                                  ^

[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:455:64: error: template argument 1 is invalid
[exec]                  typedef function Int_action;
[exec]                                                  ^

[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:455:76: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
[exec]                  typedef function Int_action;
[exec]                                                  ^


[exec] ../../third_party/cpp/json_spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp:527:49: error: invalid types 'const int[Int_action {aka int}]' for array subscript
[exec]                      | int64_p      [ new_int    ]
[exec]                                                  ^
```

Comment: gcc verssion you are using and c/cppflags, please. Without them, little chances of help.

Comment: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 
and CTX.CPPFLAGS = """-Wall -Wextra -Woverloaded-virtual
            -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings
            -Winit-self -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter
            -pthread
            -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DNOCLOCK
            -fno-omit-frame-pointer
            -fvisibility=hidden -DBOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS"""

Comment: the open-source project is voltDB and im using an old fork from 2012 for some functionality they have removed in the newer versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what the exact problem was, however after playing around with gcc versions to no avail, I updated my third_party library to gcc version I knew it worked with.

Essentially updated JSON_SPIRIT Library to its last release from 4.02 which I know works with a compiler I am now using